# Unable to perform a WiFi scan in the background

Tags: xamarin.android, android-wifi

I'm attempting to rewrite an old app that gathers WiFi signal data and uses it for internal positioning. To be actually usable, it has to be able to do this while it is not the active app and/or while the screen is off.

Getting the WiFi scanning working was very straightforward, and as long as my app is active in the foreground I consistently get scan results every 4 seconds, indefinitely. But I'm running into problems with getting it to continue doing this in the background.

The moment my app is not active or I turn off the screen:

- WifiManager.StartScan begins returning false.
- My BroadcastReceiver's OnReceive method is no longer triggered.
- WifiManager.ScanResults is empty - it doesn't even have old results in it.

These all resume working as expected once I switch back to the app or unlock my device, which is a Pixel 6a running Android 12.

From half a day of searching, I have already tried the following:

- Running this as a Foreground Service with a persistent notification.
- Acquiring a wake lock and wifi lock.
- All adaptive battery features are disabled on the device.
- Battery usage for the app is set to Unrestricted.
- Wi-Fi scan throttling is disabled on the device.
- adb has been used to disable doze on the device.
- All the necessary permissions (as documented) are in the manifest, requested by the app, and have been allowed.
- Confirmed the Foreground Service I start is still executing.

It's not clear if I am doing something incorrectly/missing something, or if I'm simply hitting an insurmountable restriction that Android is putting on WiFi scanning.

Answer (score -1):

According to your description, the only casue I can think about is that you didn't get the `Background Location Permission` for your application.

1. At first, please check if the target version in your App is Android 10.0 or heigher or not. If so, you not only need to add the `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` permissions but also the `ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION` permission and make sure you can access location in the background.
2. If the target verison is lower than Android 10.0, please check if you added the permission `ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION` and `ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION` in the AndroidManifest.xml or not. Then make sure the device show the dialog and you choose the selection which is accessing the location all the time.

For more information, please check the official document about [accessing location in the background](https://developer.android.com/training/location/background)

Comment: As I said - "All the necessary permissions (as documented) are in the manifest, requested by the app, and have been allowed." The permissions you listed happen to also be required for WiFi scanning, so I have them, but based on your link you think I'm trying to access *location* data in the background. I am not, and I don't know why you believe that link to be relevant.

Comment: The `WifiManager.StartScan` will return false when the app can't access the location. And you said that the problem appeared when the app was in background or the screen was off. There is no any code or sample. I can just think about is that your app's location request in the background is denied. @JdinklageMorgoone

Comment: You can check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54014037/android-pie-and-wifimanger-getscanresults-returns-empty-list-or-android-oreo-w), did you really grant the permission about accessing the location background at run time? @JdinklageMorgoone